# Are Pokéwalkers locked to the original copy of HeartGold/SoulSilver that they came with?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver, pokemon-hgss-pokewalker

I've just purchased Pokémon HeartGold for the Nintendo DS Lite and I was wondering if I could pair any Pokéwalker with my copy or would I need the Pokéwalker that was paired with the copy when new?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to my research you can connect any Pokewalker to any copy of HeatGold or SoulSilver (HG/SS), assuming it is clean and not currently synced to a different save file of HG/SS.

If you do not have a clean Pokewalker (one that is not currently tied to another copy of HG/SS), you can reset it without the original save file on your copy of the game.

> Go to the Pokewalker Connection Screen and hold [Down + X + L]. After that, you can connect the Pokewalker to the game to wipe the Pokewalker clean.

Note: it appears that 3DS devices and beyond have a hard time connecting to Pokewalkers. You will likely need to do this on a DS or DS Lite device.

Another note: I did not test this myself, I just did research.

Sources:

- [Nintendo Support Page for Syncing a Copy of HG/SS With Pokewalker](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3926/~/how-to-sync-the-pok%C3%A9walker)
- [Nintendo Support Page for Resetting a Pokewalker](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3925/~/how-to-reset-the-pok%C3%A9walker)
- [A Tutorial Explaining How to Reset Without the Synced File](https://atomtanned.com/home/how-to-reset-a-pokwalker-without-the-original-save-file)
- [Another Tutorial Explaining How to Reset Without the Synced File](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/ds/960099-pokemon-heartgold-version/answers/426073-how-to-reset-pokewalker-without-my-original-ds-data)